# AbstractContributionFactory Does Not Work In E4

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, e4

We have `AbstractContributionFactory`s like these:

```
final AbstractContributionFactory contributions = new AbstractContributionFactory("org.acme.mainMenu", null) {

    @Override
    public void createContributionItems(final IServiceLocator serviceLocator,
            final IContributionRoot contributionRoot) {
        String subMenuId ="org.acme.subMenu";

        final MenuManager subMenu = new MenuManager("Sub menu", subMenuId );
        contributionRoot.addContributionItem(subMenu, AlwaysEnabledExpression.INSTANCE);

        menuService.addContributionFactory(new AbstractContributionFactory("menu:" + subMenuId, null) {

            @Override
            public void createContributionItems(final IServiceLocator serviceLocator1,
                    final IContributionRoot additions) {
                additions.addContributionItem(new ActionContributionItem(new Action("Sub action") {
                }), AlwaysEnabledExpression.INSTANCE);
            }
        });
    }
};
menuService.addContributionFactory(contributions);
```

This code worked perfectly in Eclipse 3.x, but stopped working in E4. So while searching for the bug we found a lot uncommented code in the E4 framework, as much as two blocks in `WorkbenchMenuService.addContributionFactory(...)` alone. What I assume produces the bug is:

```
    // // OK, now update any managers that use this uri
    // for (Map.Entry<ContributionManager, MenuLocationURI> entry :
    // managers.entrySet()) {
    // MenuLocationURI mgrURI = entry.getValue();
    // if (mgrURI.getScheme().equals(location.getScheme())
    // && mgrURI.getPath().equals(location.getPath())) {
    // ContributionManager mgr = entry.getKey();
    // populateContributionManager(mgr, mgrURI.toString());
    // mgr.update(true);
    // }
    // }
```

According to the comments on [the associated bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?&id=411765)  a lot of people have the same problem.

Did anyone find a workaround for the bug?

Answer (score 0):

I also wanted to programmatically add some menu items to the main menu of an RCP application and was caught out by this bug.

Instead of using the `WorkbenchMenuService.addContributionFactory(...)` method I found you can add contibution items using the by extending the `ExtensionContributionFactory` class (which also has a `createContributionItems()` method), and then add this using the `org.eclipse.ui.menus` extension point as a new `menuContribution`.

I found this solution in this [blog](http://blog.vogella.com/2009/12/03/commands-menu-runtime/) by Vogella.